# R - Loop to import trimestral survey data to a single data frame to see evolution of variables

Tags: r, loops, import

I'm new to R programming. I have a function that imports trimestral data on a survey from a website to work with in R. The function from the package `eph` is as follows:

```
get_microdata(year = 2019, trimester = 2 , type = "individual")
```

I need to create a loop to import the corresponding data from year 2012 on for each trimester to a single data frame so as to be able to see the evolution of the individual variables throughout time.

Comment: Maybe something like: get_microdata2 <- function(x) {get_microdata(year = 2019, trimester = x , type = "individual")}; lapply(1:3, get_microdata2)

Comment: Thank you very much. How can I create a function to loop through the years as well? How can I then extract the survey values from the function?

Answer (score 0):

That function has been updated! Now you can download several periods (year and trimester) at once:

```
df <- get_microdata(year = 2012:2013, trimester = 1:4, type = "individual")

df <- df%>% 
  select(microdata) %>% 
  unnest(cols = "microdata")
```